# insert more than one car for one member in sql server using vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, vb.net-2010

The problem was that i wanted to add 2 rows for just one member.

Thank you for your replies. i have a members table and a membercars table. i need to add multiple cars for just one member.  Here is my code for saving cars:

```vb
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
cmd.Connection = mcon
cmd.CommandText = "insert into membercars(serial, memberid, make, model, plate, color, tag) values (@serial, @memberid, @make, @model, @plate, @color, @tag);"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serial", txtserial.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberid", txtserial.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@make", txtmake.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", txtmodel.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plate", txtplate.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color", txtcolor.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tag", txttag.Text)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()}
fillgrid()
```

And this for saving members:

```vb
cmd.Connection = mcon
strsql = "insert into members "
strsql = strsql & "(name, "
strsql = strsql & "familyname, "
strsql = strsql & "address, "
strsql = strsql & "mobile, "
strsql = strsql & "phone, "
strsql = strsql & "fax, "
strsql = strsql & "email, "
strsql = strsql & "space, "
strsql = strsql & "timezone, "
strsql = strsql & "website) "
strsql = strsql & "values ('" & txtname.Text & "', "
strsql = strsql & "'" & txtfamilyname.Text & "', "
strsql = strsql & "'" & txtaddress.Text & "', "
strsql = strsql & "'" & txtmobile.Text & "', "
strsql = strsql & "'" & txtphone.Text & "', "
strsql = strsql & "'" & txtfax.Text & "', "
strsql = strsql & "'" & txtemail.Text & "', "
strsql = strsql & "'" & txtspace.Text & "', "
strsql = strsql & Val(cmbtimezone.SelectedValue) & ", "
strsql = strsql & "'" & txtwebsite.Text & "') "
strsql += " SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('members')"
' 'strsql += " SELECT @@IDENTITY;"
' '' 
cmd.CommandText = strsql
''cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
txtsearch.Text = ""
txtserial.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
```

Thanks again for your replies :) .

Comment: Why do you need a `WHERE` clause? You're tying it to the `MemberId`. Note that you've got a mistake in your code - both `serial` and `memberid` are being set to `txtserial.Text`. If its not working, you ned to tell us what you're expecting to happen, what is happening and what errors (if any) you're getting

Comment: You mean you have to add 2 rows through INSERT in one go?

Comment: Is this any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340489/how-can-i-isolate-users-data-in-asp-net-mvc-application/20340732#20340732

Comment: if you're inserting, you need to add 2 rows for the same employee. Can you clarify the question with Table Structure plz?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. i have a members table and a membercars table. i need to add multiple cars for just one member.

Comment: Style comment here.  You are using parameters in the first query (props to you for that), but not in the second one.  Pick 1 style and use it (preferably using the one parameters!)

Comment: Another style comment.  In your second query, doing an `inset` and a `select` and not wrapping them in a `transaction` is **bad juju**.  Things could happen in your DB between the `insert` and the `select` that cause the value returned by the `select` to not be what you expected.

Comment: `AddWithValue("@memberid", txtserial.Text)` does not look right.  Also how do you link a `member` with the `car` that they own?

Comment: with the memberid. the serial of the membercars is different fom the serial of the members table.